# Merge two columns from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table "teachers" with a column called 'email', and another table "students" with a column also called 'email'.

I need to show all the e-mails both of the students and the teachers in one single column. That is, one list of all the existing e-mails no matter the position of the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `union`:

```
select email
from   teachers
union
select email
from   students
```

It concatenates the two results, and shows the overall distinct values. (In contrary to `union all` that can result in duplicate values since all row values are shown, not only the distinct values)

Just a little extra, if you *do* want to know the origin of the email address, you could do this:

```
select 'teacher' origin
,      id
,      email
from   teachers
union
select 'student' origin
,      id
,      email
from   students
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *union*:

```
select email from teachers
union
select email from students
```